# Run script without pressing enter

Tags: shell, scripting

Is there any way to run a program without pressing enter?

I could then have a script that cd's one folder up. Then I could hold down ctrl and every time i would hit a button, that script would run.

That could make life easier in the shell as I could go up the folder structure faster. And could even clear the screen each time and run ls. Or do whatever with just a single click of a button, while in the shell.

I'm using bash and my terminal emulator is Linux Mint, Xfce's default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this using bash's `.inputrc` file, the `readline` startup configuration file. First, edit the file `~/.inputrc` (this means a file named `.inputrc` in your `$HOME` directory; create it if it doesn't exist) and add this line:

```
Control-u: "cd ../\n"
```

That sets the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to insert `cd ../` followed by a newline (enter). Now, open a new terminal and you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to move one directory up. So yes, you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then move one directory up every time you press <kbd>u</kbd>.

Comment: Custom things you put in .inputrc are also available in other programs that use readline for interactive use, such as `rlwrap`.

Comment: @glennjackman that seems like a good thing, right? Or do you mean it can cause conflicts or something?

Comment: No it's a plus. The only things I have in my .inputrc are `set editing-mode vi` and `set show-mode-in-prompt on`

Comment: I don't think it is a plus, because in other utilities that use Readline (and thus .inputrc) `cd ..` makes no sense. To work around that, you could put `bind 'Control-u:"cd ..\n"'` in `.bashrc`, so it only affects Bash. Nice answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a specific task that you want to automate, but you want to speed up some command *right now* by executing it with a single keypress, why not simply use copy-paste:

1. Type the command you want to repeat, and type `<enter>`.
2. Highlight the command to the end of the line (including the newline at the end), and copy the selection to the clipboard.
3. Type control-V to paste and execute the copied command. Repeat.